# Create a new logfile every day?

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python script:

```
import logging
from datetime import date
import time

log_path: str = '/home/test/'

while True:
    date_now: str = date.today()
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_path + str(date_now) + ".log" ,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug("Main: start script")
    ......
    time.sleep(30)
```

Actually (from my point of view) this code should ensure that a new logfile is always created every day.
But I always get only the logfile from the day I start the script.
What am I doing wrong?

I have no idea what to do, because actually by changing the varibale date_now: str = date.today() always the current date is written and therefore also the logfile should always be renamed.

Comment: Your code builds a static string and passes that to `basicConfig`; the `logging` module has no idea how that string was built or what it means. If you want to change the name of the log file subsequently, you have to stop logging and start it again with a new destination.

Comment: Tangentially, calling `basicConfig` multiple times in a loop probably doesn't do what you were hoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Logging how to:**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)
If you would create a daily log file you should have a look into `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler).

You can use the *when* e.g. daily etc. to specify the type of *interval*.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the 'force' parameter to True, each time the while block is being run, instead of appending to the first file, it creates a new file, the code would look like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(force=True,filename=log_path + str(date_now) + ".log" ,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved it that way now, but I have another question about it in a moment:

```
from module import maindata
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers

logpath: str = "/home/test/log/log.log"
logger = logging.getLogger('Core')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(logpath, when='midnight', backupCount=2)
logHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)

logger.info("start script")
```

As described above, part of the code is swapped out to the maindata.py file.

This should also write to the same log file.
Do I have to enter the whole code again in this file to be able to work with logger.info?